# Optimise update of fields per object (same values)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this particular code to update 4 columns from my table per record.

```
EmailSettings::PREFERENCE_NAMES.keys.each { |k| self.update_attribute(k, false) }
```

I'm thinking that each key will hit the database.

Is there a way to optimise this code so that it will just hit the DB one time?

Comment: Are the keys different for each record?

Comment: nope. they have the same set of keys per each record. (e.g. `:newsletter`, `:profile_views`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EmailSettings::PREFERENCE_NAMES.keys.each { |k| self.attributes = {k => false} }
self.save
```

Comment: Didn't realise this one. Pure awesomeness. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) for this. Eg.

```
fields = []
keys.each do |key|
  fields << "#{key.to_s} = false"
end

Table.scope.update_all(fields.join(','))
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not attempting to update all my records at once.. im trying to update some selected attributes with same values... (e.g. true) based on what record ID is on the radar.

Comment: You mean you'd like to make one sql call to update one single object?